# Django graphene: add field resolver with saving of the type inherited from the model

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

I have a node inherited from the model:

```py
class OrderModel(models.Model):
    FAILED = "failed"
    REQUIRES_PAYMENT_METHOD = "requires_payment_method"

    ORDER_STATUSES = (
        (FAILED, FAILED),
        (REQUIRES_PAYMENT_METHOD, REQUIRES_PAYMENT_METHOD),
    )

    STATUSES_MAP_FOR_NOT_ADMINS = {
        REQUIRES_PAYMENT_METHOD: FAILED,
    }

    status = models.CharField(_('status'), choices=ORDER_STATUSES, default=NEW_ORDER, max_length=255)
 

    class Meta(object):
        db_table = 'order'
        verbose_name = _('order')
        verbose_name_plural = _('orders')

class OrderNode(PrimaryKeyMixin, DjangoObjectType):
    status = graphene.String

    def resolve_status(self, info):
        if info.context.user.is_admin:
            return self.status

        return self.STATUSES_MAP_FOR_NOT_ADMINS.get(self.status, self.status)

    class Meta:
        model = OrderModel
        filter_fields = GrantedOrderFilter.Meta.fields
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )
```

I want to add a custom status resolver to map statuses displayed for the users. But with the current implementation, I'm losing the typing for the status field. Is there any way I can save typing generated from the model and add the custom resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Found the next solution:

```py
OrderStatus = graphene.Enum('OrderStatus', {
    status: status for status, _ in GrantedOrder.ORDER_STATUSES
})

class OrderNode(PrimaryKeyMixin, DjangoObjectType):
    status = OrderStatus
```

But maybe there are more efficient solutions?